# Can you use addEventListener safely with SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, events, svg

Is **addEventListener** well supported with SVG elements across the browsers?

Eg

```
rect.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e)
{
    alert('The SVG rectangle was clicked!');
});
```

Instead of the more common:

```
rect.onmousemove = function (e)
{
    alert('The SVG rectangle was clicked!');
};
```

Comment: why not just try it and see?

Comment: You're asking two questions, I think. `addEventListener` is supported widely in modern browsers except for IE < 9 on which you need to use `attachEvent`. Strictly speaking about SVG which is not supported on IE > 8, then I would assume your assumption is correct, `addEventListener` is OK to use.

Comment: I only have 3/4 browsers on my 'puter and it seems to work on all of them.

Comment: IE < 9 doesn't support SVG so not having addEventListener is the least of your problems there.

Comment: I can see that being a bit of a bigger issue...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On browsers where SVG is suppored and `addEventListener` is supported, yes, `addEventListener` works reliably with SVG elements. SVG elements are elements, and do respond to events.

---

(Note that `mousemove` is not `click`, though. :-) )